# Extracting top 2-3 hex colors from images in R

Tags: r, image, colors

I am wondering if it is possible to extract out the main hex colors from image files containing team sports logos. I have the following vector of logos:

```
dput(team.logos[1:5))
c("https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/399.png", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/2066.png", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/42.png", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/311.png", 
"https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/160.png")
```

Using the following website (https://html-color-codes.info/colors-from-image/) - I am able to see that the hex color values in the first image (UAlbany) are `#FEBE10` for yellow, and `#3F1E6B` for the purple, as well as white.

My question is - is there any way to scrape these hex values for each image in my vector in R (so I don't have to manually load each image and click to find each hex value).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another option using the imager package...

```
require('imager')
require('data.table')

team.logos <- c("https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/399.png", 
  "https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/2066.png", 
  "https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/42.png", 
  "https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/311.png", 
  "https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/160.png")

#this function takes an image in imager's cimg format and 
#returns the hex colour codes for any colours covering more than 
#a threshold proportion of pixels (default is set to 0.05)
getHexPrimaries <- function(img, pcnt.threshold = 0.05){

    #convert cimg to workable format
    channel.labels <- c('R','G','B','A')[1:dim(img)[4]]
    img <- as.data.table(as.data.frame(img))
    img[,channel := factor(cc ,labels=channel.labels)]
    img <- dcast(img, x+y ~ channel, value.var = "value")

    #sort by unique rgb combinations and identify the primary colours
    colours.sorted <- img[, .N, by=list(R,G,B)][order(-N)]
    colours.sorted[ , primary := N/sum(N) > pcnt.threshold]

    #convert to hex
    hex.primaries <- 
      apply(colours.sorted[primary==TRUE], 1, function(row){
        hex <- rgb(row[1], row[2], row[3], maxColorValue=1)
        hex
      })

    hex.primaries
}

hex.list <- lapply(team.logos, function(logo.url) {
  download.file(logo.url,'temp.png', mode = 'wb')
  img <- load.image('temp.png')
  getHexPrimaries(img)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.  The png library allows one to load a RGB file and then it is a matter of converting the three channels into the Hex codes.
I confirmed the codes are correct for the first image, good luck with the rest.

```
logos<-c("https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/399.png", 
  "https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/2066.png", 
  "https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/42.png", 
  "https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/311.png", 
  "https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/ncaa/500/160.png")

plot(NA, xlim = c(0, 2), ylim = c(0, 5), type = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
library(png)

for (filen in seq_along(logos)) {
  #download and read file
  #this will overwrite the file each time, 
  #create a list if you would like to save the files for the future.
  download.file(logos[filen], "file1.png")
  image1<-readPNG("file1.png")

  #plot if desired
  #plot(NA, xlim = c(0, 2), ylim = c(0, 5), type = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
  rasterImage(image1, 0, filen-1, 1, filen)

  #convert the rgb channels to Hex
  outR<-as.hexmode(as.integer(image1[,,1]*255))
  outG<-as.hexmode(as.integer(image1[,,2]*255))
  outB<-as.hexmode(as.integer(image1[,,3]*255))
  #paste into to hex value
  hex<-paste0(outR, outG, outB)
  #remove the white and black
  hex<-hex[hex != "ffffff" & hex != "000000"]
  #print top 5 colors
  print(head(sort(table(hex), decreasing = TRUE)))
}
```

Here is the sample output, the hex color with the number of pixels with that color.

```
 print(head(sort(table(hex), decreasing = TRUE)))
 #hex
 #c3c4c6 00275d 00265c c2c3c5 001e57 00255c 
 #67929  39781    838    744    649    633
```